# CMD check if specific USB is connected

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-services

i want to write a service that checks if a specific USB-Device is connected and then executes a command.
I need it to be universal, so without installing other software, just in cmd.

Ive found this command, that shows all USB-Devices, but I would need a command that just returns something like true or false if the specific device is connected.
Any ideas?

```
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'USB%'" get /value
```

Comment: A batch file is not a service, and should not be used as one. Consider using C# in Visual Studio for creating them instead. Also, what exactly is it that defines the specific USB device you're hoping to detect?

Comment: I'm trying to detect if a USB label printer is connected, and I guess each USB-Device has a special ID that could be checked by some command

Comment: `wmic ... |find "specific string"` returns `0` if the string was found and `1` if it wasn't